# make index started with mathcal mode in the right order

Tags: indexing, sorting

I want to make index something like:

`$\mathcal{P}$-vector\index{$\mathcal{p}$-vector}`

but when indexed it comes  before words started with 'A' instead of being after 'O' words.

Answer (score 10):

If you are using makeindex you can specify both the sorting string and the typeset version for the document. By default `@` is the separator although it can be changed in the index style.

```
  \index{p-vector@$\mathcal{P}$-vector}
```