# How to define a macro that calls \index?

Tags: indexing

I would like to define a command which calls `\index` with its argument and gives a page-formatting style, like so:

```
\newcommand{\defstyle}[1]{\textbf{#1}}
\newcommand{\indexdef}[1]{\index{#1|defstyle}}
```

Unfortunately, when I do this, index commands like

```
$\phi$-foo\indexdef{$\phi$-foo}
\newpage
$\phi$-foo\index{$\phi$-foo}
```

result in an index containing two separate entries rather than one.  I can see that this is because the `.idx` file contains

```
\indexentry{$\phi $-foo|defstyle}{1}
\indexentry{$\phi$-foo}{2}
```

with an extra space in the first case.  I can even guess something of where that space comes from: I've gathered that `\index` has a sort of verbatim-like behavior, which the extra indirection of `\indexdef` is suppressing just enough for something else (what?) to insert a random extra space after the `\phi` (why?).  The real question is, how to fix it?

I can think of two "solutions" so far.  One is to just call `\index{...|defstyle}` everywhere instead of `\indexdef`.  The other is to use indirection in both cases:

```
\newcommand{\myindex}[1]{\index{#1}}
```

and then use `\myindex` instead of `\index`.  But both would require a search-and-replace in a long document that already uses both `\index` and `\indexdef`.  Is there a solution that will let me keep both?  I tried

```
\let\myindex\index
\renewcommand{\index}[1]{\myindex{#1}}
```

but this doesn't work (why not?).

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't work"? What package are you using for making the index? In any case, sorting will be wrong; probably something like `\index{phi-foo@$\phi$-foo}` is better.

Comment: (It really would be best if you provided a proper minimal example.) The basic answer is you need to do something like `\indexdef{$\string\phi$-foo}` (but it really does depend on whether you are using some funky indexing packages, etc.).  This seems hard to automate since the use of `\string` in this case needs to fall between the `$...$`.  Also, @egreg's point about improper sorting really deserves consideration!

Comment: I guess one solution for `$\phi$-foo` is, assuming it needs to be indexed more than once or twice, is to wrap the whole thing in a command (say `\phifoo`) that prints the term in the text and creates an index entry.  Then it would be simple to maintain consistency across a large document.  (Of course, although LaTeX is great for the separation of form and content, I too often only realize how better separation is possible part way through a complex document, which means annoying search-and-replaces. There is certainly something to be said for 'planning ahead' when it comes to macro-writing!)

Comment: In the real example, I have things sorted correctly.  I just took that part out to simplify the code, in order to focus the question on what I was actually asking, instead of irrelevancies like how things are sorted.

Comment: @jon: What more do you want in terms of a minimal example?  Just wrap the code above in a begin/end document and you've got it.  Should I provide the begin/end document for you?

Comment: @egreg: by "it doesn't work" I mean that it results in the same undesired behavior as before: two separate index entries.

Comment: @MikeShulman That's a known problem. But you first should consider sorting. See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/53420/make-index-started-with-mathcal-mode-in-the-right-order

Comment: @MikeShulman -- Yes, as the asker of the question, you should provide the example, rather than make people trying to help have to create one.  Often (not always, of course) just creating the minimal example will point to a/the solution.  Also, did you try my suggestion?

Comment: @egreg: As I already said, I have solved the sorting issue in my actual document. I removed the sorting @ commands for the purposes of a minimal example, in case they were what was causing the problem (they aren't). What exactly is a 'known problem'? My entire question?

Comment: @jon: I have made the minimal example: the code above is copied and pasted from it. I assumed I didn't need to include the boilerplate wrapping, sorry. I don't think your suggestion has any advantage over the two solutions I wanted to improve on.

Comment: The minimal example is (also) for the people trying to help you.  If I want to try to locate the source of your difficulties, I need to construct a fake document for a problem I don't have in order to try to help.  By providing a real, compilable document, you encourage others to help you.  So, naturally, you don't *have* to provide one....  As for my suggestion, the point is more to show that where the source of your problem lies, which is compounded by having an index element composed of math and text, and why there is no easy solution. Your best bet, IMO, is to 'refactor' your index macros.